# Stargate the film: Is Anubis in the movie?

Tags: stargate, stargate-movie

Anubis is a god, right?
Then why is the goa uld guard, who died because the ring transport cut off his head, why is he called Anubis? Am I even making sense?
Is Anubis a goauld?

Comment: Best to think of the movie as a separate continuity, IMO.

Comment: If it was the same Anubis, the rings would have just cut off the host's head, maybe they could have just transferred the symbiote to another host.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I thought Goa'uld die when their host dies, though I can't immediately find any evidence of that (or remember any proof) come to think of it. Certainly they wouldn't be able to live outside of a host for long unless Janet's supplying some tasty electricity and saline or whatever that fluid was...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Apparently the usual [Horus Guards](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Horus_Guard) of Ra had one guy in a jackal helmet, named Anubis. Two options:

- **Early installment weirdness.**
  When they made the original movie, they didn't have the ten-season series and the characters mapped out.
- There are plenty of places where *Jesus* is a common first name. Even more places have names with *Theo-* in it. So why wouldn't one of Ra's guards be named Anubis?

Comment: Good answer, pretty much exactly what I was thinking

Comment: "Why wouldn't one of Ra's guards be named Anubis?" Because naming your child after one of Goa'uld is a great way to get the child, yourself, your family, and every one you've ever known executed.

Comment: @T.J.L. In the canon of the series, for sure especially considering Ra and consorts banished Anubis for undescribable crimes. But #2 makes sense in light of #1. You have to remember the two have been made by different people at different times. My guess would be the movie went with a general Egyptian theme, with top dog being the Sun God Ra, and his crew being other lesser gods. Like his two trusted human guards being Anubis and Horus. The series obviously developed a different mythos where Anubis and Heru'ur are Goa'uld themselves. But in the frame of the movie, it makes sense.

Comment: @AmiralPatate It was a joke. :)

Comment: @T.J.L. But it's actually a good illustration of the differences between the movie and the series.

Comment: @T.J.L. On the other hand, Ra (re)naming one of his guards after Anubis is a good way to insult the memory of his banished foe...

Comment: In the movie, Ra was the last of his kind.

Comment: @StopHarmingMonica As far the humans know, and it is recorded. We don't ever get in the movie Ra stating that he's the last of his kind. So that could be a confusion from the humans on Earth who got a garbled story. (Presumably this wasn't the actual intent of the writers.)

Comment: @StopHarmingMonica *"Hey, puny humans, Ra here.  I am totally a god, fear and worship me!  Oh, and I am also definitely the* last *god alive - the others are absolutely dead, there is no one else for you to worship, and no one who can save you from me.  Honest."*

Comment: @o.m. the direct link would be https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Anubis_(Human)